# Firebase Spinner Dropdown not populating

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

My spinner seems to not be populating when I try to get the data from firebase. Please help me.
Here is the code for initializing the spinner:

```
    private void initLocation() {
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Location");
        ArrayList<Location> list = new ArrayList<>();
        myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot issue : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        list.add(issue.getValue(Location.class));
                    }
                    Log.d("FirebaseData", "Data loaded successfully: " + list.size() + " items");
                    ArrayAdapter<Location> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(requireContext(),  android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, list);
                    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                    locationSp.setAdapter(adapter);
                } else {
                    Log.d("FirebaseData", "No data found");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                Log.e("FirebaseData", "Data loading canceled with error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });

    }
```

This is the Location.java file:

```
public class Location {
    private int Id;
    private String loc;

    public Location(String loc) {
        this.loc = loc;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        Id = id;
    }

    public String getLoc() {
        return loc;
    }

    public void setLoc(String loc) {
        this.loc = loc;
    }

}
```

I want the spinner to be populated but when I run the app, the spinner text is blank and when I press it, it doesn't drop down anything.

Update, here is the database structure:

```
  "Location": [
    {
      "Id": 0,
      "loc": "LA california"
    },
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "loc": "NY manhattan"
    }
  ],
  "Price": [
    {
      "Id": 0,
      "Value": "1$ - 10$"
    },
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Value": "10$ - 30$"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "Value": "more than 30$"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: share your logs

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Besides that, tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I have updated my answer. I really appreciate the instruction though. To answer the question, the application runs but it doesn't populate the dropdown. A quick fix was to change and get the specific location of the .getInstance() method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get any other errors. The application runs but the dropdown doesn't populate. I have already fixed the issue by updating how I get my database.

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("database location");
```